# Calling a Rails application helper in Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have Googled this and can't seem to find an

```
class MyWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include ApplicationHelper

  worker code.... etc....

  myapphelper(arg)

end
```

I have a simple worker which at the end calls an application helper but I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `myapphelper'
```

I thought adding the `include ApplicationHelper` would do the trick.

**UPDATE**

So lets add some more detail.  The helper (which in fact was actually a method in my application controller) in question was originally this:

```
def add_history(resource, action, note)

    resource.history.create(action: action, note: note, user_id: current_user.id) if resource.present? && action.present? && note.present?

end
```

The idea here is I have a quick way to add a paper trail to a Model.  I realized that I should perhaps not pass an actual object into the method because (like the Sidekiq docs indicate) if that object changes you could get into trouble.  So I changed it to this:

```
  def add_history(klass, id , action, note)

    resource = klass.constantize.find_by(id: id)
    resource.history.create(action: action, note: note, user_id: current_user.id) if resource.present? && action.present? && note.present?

  end
```

Now when I include this as a Module the current_user.id fails because that's set in the ApplicationController.

So lets revise my question: would the best practice to just add current_user.id as a argument to my module method or somehow keep this in the Application Controller etc.?

If I am totally off track here and this type of logic should go somewhere else please let me know.

Comment: ApplicationHelpers are not intended to be used inside of anything except views.   Consider moving your method to a plain old module, and include that.

Comment: Hmmm... you are right... I think I approached that helper the wrong way entirely.  If you add this as an answer I will accept it because it is right as afar as I can tell even though you were pointing out the obvious to me :)

Comment: inclusion doesn't work because this module is out of worker  vision scope. You also need require this file like  `require '/filepath'`

Comment: Gladly and thanks!    Good luck!

Comment: just add argument which passes current_user id

Answer (score 3):

You could accomplish the behavior by doing something like:

```
class HistoryWorker
   include Sidekiq::Worker
   include History # or whatever you want to call it

  def perform(klass, id , action, note, user_id)
    add_history(klass, id, action, note, user_id)
  end

end

module History
  def add_history(klass, id, action, note, user_id)
    resource = klass.constantize.find_by(id: id)
    resource.history.create(action: action, note: note, user_id: user_id) if resource.present? && action.present? && note.present?
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :save_history

  def save_history
     HistoryWorker.perform_async(class: resource.class.name, id: resource.id, action: params[:action], note: 'some note', user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Apologize for any dumb syntax errors, but that's more or less the structure you want.

That being said, using a Module is probably overkill in this case, especially if you do not intend on re-using its method elsewhere.  In that case, I'd just add a private method inside the worker.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did.  I kept it as a straight module as I will call this all over my app as various rows get created, updated etc.  I will point out that naming your module the same as your model name has issues.  I did what you have and after restarting my app I had all sorts of errors.  I didn't dig into it too much as it was easier to just re-name it `HistoryModule` vs `History`

Comment: Oh, interesting.   It's possible you're using a gem or some third-party code that has already claimed the `History` namespace, as I don't think Rails declares that anywhere.   Anyhow, glad you got it sorted out.